# jQuery special div height animation

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate, height

Is there a way to animate a div height in jQuery by allowing both the top and bottom of the div to expand?  I want to do something like on the LDS homepage: www.lds.org.  The div on the left of the top banner image is the type of thing I'm going for.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the illusion that it is expanding in both up and down directions, by moving the div upwards while animating it's height.

```
<html>

<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready( function() {
    var d = $('div');
    d.css('top', '250px').css('height', 0);
    d.animate( {
        height: '500px',
        top: 0
    } , 3000 );
} );
</script>
<style>
div {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background: #f00;
    position: absolute;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you tell me why the position has to be declared as absolute?